# Angular Strap doesn't seem to work with ngInspector (plug-in). Any one know why?

Tags: angularjs, angular-strap

I can get the plug-in to work just fine, and for a *long* time couldn't figure out why it stopped working with my project. But after I had a suspicion that it was a module, I commented out 'mcrea.strap' and sure enough ng-Inspector worked fine!

Anyone also come across this problem?